# upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10, will boot to runlevel 3, but not 5

Tags: upgrade

Yesterday I updated from 18.04 to 20.04.  There were some hiccups related to ld.so.conf.d.  I disabled those and was able to run with desktop manager etc for hours.

Then I proceeded to upgrade to 20.10 using the do-release-upgrade (after updating the proper /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades file with Prompt=normal.

The process got to the "hit return to reboot" I did, but the computer (Dell XPS 13) never came up.  After some working with editing the boots, I am able to get it booted at runlevel 3, and login with my normal userid.  Now, I'm lost as to where to look (e.g., which log files) to trace down the problem with getting to runlevel 5 (i.e., desktop manager mode).  Any ideas?

Comment: I would start with /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the /var/syslog pointer.  I did check that and found:

```
Dec 14 06:35:10 halibut nautilus[37980]: Could not load a pixbuf from /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png.#012This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
    Dec 14 06:35:10 halibut org.gnome.Nautilus[37980]: Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /org/gtk/libgtk/icons/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)
```

Based on a web search I then performed an apt reinstall of shared-mime-info and gdk-pixbuf2.  My system is working now (w/ nomodeset still, but will get to that).

Thanks again.